# ruby on rails, adding a partial to each html page in the system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently working on a project which has ROR in backend, I need to add a noscript tag to every page in the system to show a banner to the user.

Does ROR provide an easy way to add a piece of html to every page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the application layout file `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.  That file gets loaded for every view unless you have disabled this layout or have used a different layout.

If you have multiple layouts then place the `<noscript>...</noscript>` in a partial and render the partial in all the layouts.